How do I connect my Android device via Bluetooth to my PC which has a Bluetooth 5.0 USB Dongle?
I am writing an android application that originally connects to an HC-05 bluetooth module, with communication back and forth. I want to be able to connect it to my PC that has a Gembird Bluetooth 5.0 USB Dongle using the same application, but it fails to connect. I keep getting a timeout exception.
On the PC, the name of the device, Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI), as well as the service id RFCOMM, suggests that the USB dongle is a serial communications device just as the HC-05 module I am using.
I am able to pair and connect my Android mobile phone to the PC in its own settings fine, transfer files, etc. Same with bluetooth earbuds. The USB Bluetooth 5.0 Dongle works fine for that.
On Android, I have the same code for connecting to bluetooth, that works with HC-05:
 private static final UUID CONNECTION_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

 static boolean connect(BluetoothDevice device) {

    try{

        if(btAdapter == null) {

            //AlertMessage.show("Alert!", "Bluetooth Adapter not found...", true);
            Toast.makeText(CurrentContext.get(), "Bluetooth Adapter not found...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        else if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {

            //AlertMessage.show("Alert!", "Bluetooth Adapter is not enabled...", true);
            Toast.makeText(CurrentContext.get(), "Bluetooth Adapter is not enabled...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

        if(btSocket != null && btSocket.isConnected()) {

            if(btDevice == null) {

                //AlertMessage.show("Alert!", "Bluetooth Device could not be found...", true);
                Toast.makeText(CurrentContext.get(), "Bluetooth Device could not be found...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            else {

                //AlertMessage.show("Alert!", "Already connected to: " + btDevice.getName(), true);
                Toast.makeText(CurrentContext.get(), "Already connected to: " + btDevice.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(CurrentContext.get(), "Connecting. Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        btDevice = device;

        if(btDevice == null) {

            //AlertMessage.show("Alert!", "Bluetooth Device could not be found...", true);
            Toast.makeText(CurrentContext.get(), "Bluetooth Device could not be found...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

        btSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(CONNECTION_UUID);
        if(btSocket == null) {

            //AlertMessage.show("Alert!", "Bluetooth Socket could not be found...", true);
            Toast.makeText(CurrentContext.get(), "Bluetooth Socket could not be found...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        btSocket.connect();

        mmInputStream = new DataInputStream(btSocket.getInputStream());

        beginInputStreamListener();
    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        //AlertMessage.show("Alert!", "There was an unresolved problem...", true);
        Toast.makeText(CurrentContext.get(), "Could not connect to: " + device.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        reset();
        return false;
    }

    Toast.makeText(CurrentContext.get(), "Connected to: " + btDevice.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}

However, as mentioned, it will not connect to the PC. It gives me a timedout exception on btSocket.connect();
I have been suggested to change the UUID to the corresponding Bluetooth dongle's, but I am unable to find the UUID. I tried using PowerShell command Get-PnpDeviceProperty -InstanceId "YOUR_DEVICE_INSTANCE_ID" | Where-Object { $_.KeyName -match 'Service' }, but it returns RFCOMM as mentioned before, suggesting that it is the same protocol as the HC-05. Yet, it simply doesn't work. The UUID should be the same.
The goal is to send data back and forth with my own program on the PC through serial communication, to imitate the HC-05 module's serial communication on the arduino.

You must run Bluetooth server on PC side that listens on the specified (the same) service UUID.

@MikePetrichenko I'm a total idiot. Thank you.
